# how to compare the elements of array

Tags: php

I'm trying to fetch `leave_dates` from mysql database the output of mysql query is given below

```
08/01/2016, 08/02/201608/16/2016, 08/17/2016, 08/18/2016, 08/19/2016, 08/20/2016, 08/21/2016, 08/22/2016, 08/23/2016
```

This is the code:

```
$sql="SELECT leave_dates from employee_leaves WHERE   employee_leave_employee_id='24'";
$query= mysql_query($sql);
$input="08/04/2016, 08/02/2016,08/16/2016";
$input_array=explode(",", $he);
//$count=count($ha);

while($rc=mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    $dates=$rc['leave_dates'];
    $dat=explode(",", $dates);
    $result = array_merge(array_diff($dat, $input_array), array_diff($input_array, $dat));
    echo $result[1];
}
```

The issue is I'm not getting my desired result all I wanted to compare the elements of these two arrays and display any diff element if exists.

Comment: You have spaces in `$input`. But you only `explode` on the `,`. Remove the spaces.

Comment: @Terminus still not working

Comment: Does `leave_dates` also have spaces?

Comment: no there are no spaces in leave_dates @Terminus

Comment: it looks like it has spaces from the output you pasted. It also appears to be missing a comma near the beginning `08/01/2016, 08/02/201608/16/2016`

Answer (score 0):

Do this simple solution, Try to add you array into there demo array variable..

```
 $array1 = array(10, 15, 20, 25);
    $array2 = array(10, 15, 100, 150);
    $output = array_merge(array_diff($array1, $array2), array_diff($array2, $array1));


    // $output will be (20, 25, 100, 150);
```

Answer (score 0):

array_diff only work one way, giving you items in first array that are not present in the other array.

```
$result = array_merge(array_diff($dat, $input_array), array_diff($input_array, $dat));
```